# Full private property for setter and getter

Tags: vb.net

I would like to make my property fully private (get and set) if so is it better to just use private variable instead of property or use private property itself?

**EDIT (for further questions)**

```
'ok i can use _foo within class and Foo in outside classes
Private _foo As String
Private Property Foo() As String
    Get
        Return _foo
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _foo = value
    End Set
End Property

'issue as cannot use _name with class
Property Name as String

'it's ok i can use _age within class but looks not good as e.g above Name... without undescore..
Private _age as Integer
```

Comment: @Bugs so either one or another can be used but i think i will use Private variable instead of private property. But one thing i dont like to see is my class contains properties mixed with private variables dont like how it looks ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real difference between:

```
Private _foo As String
Private Property Foo() As String
    Get
        Return _foo
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _foo = value
    End Set
End Property
```

And:

```
Private Foo As String
```

The keyword `Private` keeps it within the scope of the class. That's all. You now can't access `Foo` in either context from anywhere other than where it was declared.

There are a couple of advantages to using a `Property` however. For one, you can make a property `ReadOnly` for access:

```
Private _foo As String
Public ReadOnly Property Foo() As String
    Get
        Return _foo
    End Get
End Property
```

This allows for access outside of the class it originates from. You can do all the setting on `_foo` within the originating class without worrying about this being changed outside the class.

Another advantage to a `Property` is you can raise events and/or log changes:

```
Private _foo As String
Public Property Foo() As String
    Get
        Return _foo
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If Not (value = _foo) Then
            _foo = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

You can also validate the value being set and/or update other private fields:

```
Private _foo As Integer
Public WriteOnly Property Foo() As Integer
    Set(value As Integer)
        _foo = value
        If _foo > 10 Then
            _bar = True
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Private _bar As Boolean
Public ReadOnly Property Bar() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _bar
    End Get
End Property
```

A `Property` can also be used for `DataBinding` whilst a field cannot.

I'm sure there are other differences however this should give you a good indication as to whether you require the use of a `Property` or whether a field is good enough.